# Constants for resource types in Android

Tags: android, resources, constants, hardcode

Are there constants for the various resource types (ie: "drawable") in Android?

I want to code some conditional logic based on the return value of [getResourceTypeName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceTypeName(int)) and I would prefer to avoid hardcoding the resource types.

Example:

```
final String type = context.getResources().getResourceTypeName(resid);
if ("drawable".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
    // Something
} else if ("xml".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
    // Something else
}
// TODO: Replace above strings with system constants
```

(I can create my own constants, obviously, but I would prefer to use system constants to ensure upward compatibility)

Comment: Could you provide an example of a use case? Some pseudocode or something that exemplifies what you are trying to do

Comment: Edited question to include code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be hardcoded:

http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch?q=\%22drawable\%22+\%22xml\%22&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git